# SUMIF formula runs partially

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, sumifs

I am using a `SUMIF` formula nested inside an `IF` statement. Sometimes my formula computes what I need to happen, other times it shows as an error. The order of the Logic is as follows:

```
If(Cell Value="No Change",Cost/Total Cost of No Change,
If(Cell Value="Partial Sale",Cost/Total Cost of Partial Sale,
If(Cell Value="Partial Purchase",Cost/Total Cost of Partial Purchase,
If(Cell Value="New Purchase",Cost/Total Cost of New Purchase,
False))))
```

An example of what I wrote:

```
=IF(CK8="No Change",BY8/SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,"No Change",$P$8:$P$4996),
 IF(CK8="Partial Sale",BY8/sumif($CK$8:$CK$4996,"Partial Sale",$P$8:$P$4996),
 IF(CK8="Partial Purchase",BY8/SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,"Partial Purchase",$P$8:$P$4996),
 IF(CK8="New Purchase",BY8/SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,"New Purchase",$P$8:$P$4996),FALSE))))
```

My issue comes when `Cell Value="Partial Sale"` or `"Partial Purchase"`, I keep getting an error. I check my `Cost` column and every cell has a value (range from negatives to posties including zero). I have also converted this into a `SUMIFS` formula and no change occurred. I also used the `*` before and after my text values because I saw somewhere it was required, but no change. What could be the issue?

Comment: What error do you get ? `#DIV!0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the formula and it only gives error *(`#DIV/0!` as pointed by @Robin Mackenzie)* when `SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,$CK8,$P$8:$P$4996)=0` you can check that condition with these formulas:

```
=BY8/SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,"Partial Sale",$P$8:$P$4996)
=BY8/SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,"Partial Purchase",$P$8:$P$4996)
```

Also there is not need for the nested `IF`'s, try this formula instead:

```
=BY8/SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,CK8,$P$8:$P$4996)
```

The formula above just replaces the values of the list

```
"No Change", "Partial Sale", "Partial Purchase", "New Purchase"
```

with the value of the cell used to compare the list against: `CK8`

In other words:

This is the original formula

```
=IF(CK8=[ListValueA1],BY8/SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,[ListValueB1],$P$8:$P$4996),
 IF(CK8=[ListValueA2],BY8/sumif($CK$8:$CK$4996,[ListValueB2],$P$8:$P$4996),
 IF(CK8=[ListValueA3],BY8/SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,[ListValueB3],$P$8:$P$4996),
 IF(CK8=[ListValueA4],BY8/SUMIF($CK$8:$CK$4996,[ListValueB4],$P$8:$P$4996),FALSE))))
```

where `[ListValueAx] = [ListValueBx]`

if `CK8=[ListValueAx]` then we can replace `[ListValueBx]` with `CK8` 
and eliminate the nested `IF`'s